# Como buscar uma palavra exata com o comando grep

Tags: linux, bash

Bom, sempre que eu uso o comando grep ele procura uma palavra que contenha a palavra desejada + qualquer coisa, como posso fazer ele entender que eu só quero aquela palavra e mais nada?
ex:

```
ps aux|grep bc
```

em vez dele procurar

```
...... bcache
...... bclink
...... bc
......
......
```

ele procure apenas a palavra bc

```
......bc
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Utilize a opção `--word-regexp` ou simplesmente `-w`, por exemplo:

```
ps aux | grep -w bc
```

O parâmetro supramencionado irá retornar apenas a linha que contenha a palavra informada (e não apenas uma parte dela) precedida de caracteres não constituinte (letras, números e sublinhado).

Comment: Voto meu, e ainda ganha medalha ;)